Move one file in multiple folders to new folder
I have a directory structure like this:
Source Folder
I need to copy file1a, file1aa, file1aaa ( or order by name ascending) to New Folder. How can I do it in Windows?
expected results:
Target Folder
In Real Case, i have list.txt from several folders containing several files
list.txt
List.txt
Folder and File Example
Folder and File Example1
Folder and File Example2

Your question is very unclear, but as I understand, you have a file 'List.txt' with names of files you want to copy to a target folder named 'NewFolder' and rename the files in a sequent order like 'file1a, file1aa, file1aaa', So if this is what you want, you can use something like this PowerShell script

$TargetFoldaer = 'C:\Users\Admin\NewFolder'
if ( -not (Test-Path $TargetFoldaer) ) { New-Item $TargetFoldaer -ItemType Directory }
$i = 1
Get-Content list.txt | foreach {
    $FileName = 'file1' + 'a' * $i
    $Destination = Join-Path $TargetFoldaer $FileName
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination $Destination
    $i++
}

If you just want to copy, not rename the files, symply use this:
$TargetFoldaer = C:\Users\Admin\NewFolder

if ( -not (Test-Path $TargetFoldaer) ) { New-Item $TargetFoldaer -ItemType Directory }

Get-Content list.txt | Copy-Item -Destination $TargetFoldaer


just copy, not rename the files. file1a, file1aa, file1aaa just example.

done, $TargetFoldaer = C:\Users\Admin\NewFolder change to $TargetFoldaer = 'C:\Users\Admin\NewFolder' .
Thank you very much for the answer and solution.
